# How to change border thickness of boxPlus() in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have a `boxPlus()` object in my R Shiny app. I want to make borders thicker. How do I do that?

Comment: can you please give a minimal working example so we could help?

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use CSS with your R Shiny code -  [style your RShiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) - and set the border parameter similar to:

```
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
```

Comment: thank you. Can you please provide a full example how such CSS styling can be used with RShiny to address my question?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an external css file you can include like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
            
    includeCSS("styles.css"),
```

in css you might want to link to an HTML element, you can make one containing your BoxPlus and in CSS write similar:

```
div {
   border-style: solid
   border-width: 5px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px
   margin: auto;
}
```

or even include CSS + HTML element inside BoxPlus:

```
BoxPlus(
     div("NameOftheElemeent", style = "border-style: solid, border-width: 5px, width:100%, height:100%;")
)
```